# Grep not working in script but on console

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, console

I have a problem with a script. I have a voltage meter connected to a serial USB device(ttyUSB1). 
The smart meter needs an initial sequence and shortly followed by a second command to give all of it's information. That works fine. 1.8.0*00(000898.46) for example comes in this is the line I am interested in. The number in brackets is the kWh number i want. If i open a second terminal and do a cat /dev/ttyUSB1 it works fine and i can see the information coming in. After 4 to 5 seconds the line I want comes in. But the script is not working. If i start a script in one terminal it keeps waiting. Grep is not finishing. If I start it in a second terminal then the first terminal gets finished. Or just the grep 1.8.0 /dev/ttyUSB1 -m1 in another terminal works but not in the script.
I tried different methos with read and so none worked. To be honest i don't understand much of scripting and always succeed somehow but here nothings helped :(

Please help. Thank you! 
Arne

here the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo start
echo $'\x2f\x3f\x21\x0d' > /dev/ttyUSB1
sleep 1
echo ask
echo $'\x06\x30\x30\x30\x0d' > /dev/ttyUSB1
echo  wait
grep 1.8.0 /dev/ttyUSB1 -m1
echo end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a file with voltimeter's output and grep from that file:

```
#! /bin/bash

dev=/dev/ttyUSB1
file=/tmp/testfile

(tail -f $dev | tee $file) & # let's continuously copy in background
echo start
echo $'\x2f\x3f\x21\x0d' > $dev
sleep 1
echo ask
echo $'\x06\x30\x30\x30\x0d' > $dev
echo  wait
grep 1.8.0 $file # lets get the info from the file instead
echo end 
sleep 1
exit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it creates /tmp/testfile but it is empty. If I open a second terminal with cat /dev/USBtty1 it shows that the data is coming in I think the script somehow gets no grip to the incoming data from ttyUSB1. Maybe I have to make 2 scripts one that makes the meter to send data and a second that tries to get my number. Actually i wanted just one that gives me the data back. wonder why its not working :(

Comment: Is it /dev/USBtty1 or /dev/ttyUSB1?

Comment: /dev/ttyUSB1 sorry not the other way around